# Pandas Pivot or Transpose multiple columns (long to wide format)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format, pivot

I am trying to pivot the dataframe from long to wide format. However, seems like not able to reach the final stage with either ***pivot*** or ***transpose***. Same with ***stack*** method.

Original Dataframe

```
| foo | bar | tar |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | A   | AA  |
| one | NaN | BB  |
| two | C   | NaN |
```

Desired Dataframe

```
| foo | A   | B   | C   | AA  | BB  | CC  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| one | bar | NaN | NaN | tar | tar | tar |
| two | NaN | NaN | bar | tar | tar | NaN |
```

Tried Code till now.

```
pd.DataFrame(df.stack()).T.reset_index()

df.pivot(index='foo',columns='bar').reset_index()
```

Code to create dataframe.

```
foo = ['one','one','two']
bar = ['A',np.NaN,'C']
tar = ['AA','BB', np.NaN]

df = {'foo':foo,'bar':bar,'tar':tar}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Comment: Can you add more rows where `bar` takes value like 'B' and  `tar` takes value like `CC`. Or all possible values of `bar` and `tar` are taken as input

Comment: Ideally NaN should be the value if we do not have value available for that place.

Comment: Hi, in the expected dataframe, why does `AA` have tar on rows one and two even though it appears only on row one in the initial dataframe, but `A`, which is in the same situation, has only bar in the first row of the expected dataframe? And why does `CC`, which is not in the initial dataframe, has `tar` on first row in the expected dataframe, instead of second row or even both rows, for instance?